# Enterprise Library 5.0: Bug in exception logging to rolling log file?

Tags: enterprise-library

So, what I'm trying to accomplish is that my exceptions get logged into the rolling log file (which I use for other things, especially tracing - which is VERY important in the environment I'm working in - too).

Problem is that I get all traces into rolling.log, but the exceptions get logged into files with the following name scheme:

{guid}rolling.log

Smells like a bug...

**Edit:**

Found the solution. The log - file is locked, EntLib creates a new one with that "Guided" (pun not intended, it just happened) name. Case closed. :-)